# Equation inside Intertext{{} under falign{} environment

Tags: math-mode, align

Can i use `$` Equation `$` inside and outside `\intertext{}` under `flalign` environment. Because of these two lines my all equations got justified to left. Please help in this regard.

Before adding it is properly justified wrt center

```
 \begin{flalign*} & & \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}&=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}{s}}{s^{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}{s}+{\omega}^{2}} & & \ \end{flalign*}
```

After adding bellow text, instead of center it is justified toward left

```
{\intertext{On comparing}} ${\omega}={\sqrt{K_i}}$ \quad ${\delta}=\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}}$\
```

Answer (score 2):

The two equations have no natural alignment point, so the best is to use two `equation*` environment. I can't recommend having the phrase “On comparing” on the same level as the second equation.

Compare the following results and decide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Perhaps this is what you'd like to have,
\begin{flalign*}
&& \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}&=\frac{\omega^{2}+2\delta\omega s}
                           {s^{2}+2\delta\omega s+\omega^{2}} && \\
&\text{On comparing}
 & \omega&=\sqrt{K_{i}} \quad \delta =\frac{K_{p}}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}} &&
\end{flalign*}
but I can't recommend it, because the text should be on a line by itself.
Much better is simply using two equations
\begin{equation*}
\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{\omega^{2}+2\delta\omega s}
                       {s^{2}+2\delta\omega s+\omega^{2}}
\end{equation*}
On comparing
\begin{equation*}
\omega=\sqrt{K_{i}} \quad \delta =\frac{K_{p}}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Avoid overusing braces, I removed all the unnecessary ones, adding some recommended ones instead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need for `flalign` here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*} & & \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}&=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}{s}}
                                {s^{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}{s}+{\omega}^{2}} & &\\
\intertext{On comparing}
 & & \omega=\sqrt{K_i} \quad \delta & =\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}} &&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{align*}
 \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}&=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}{s}}
                                {s^{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}{s}+{\omega}^{2}} \\
\intertext{On comparing}
 \omega=\sqrt{K_i} \quad \delta & =\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can't use `$` inside `flalign` but inside `\intertext` and `\text` you can.

If you load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` (`mathtools` loads `amsmath` by itself), you get `\shortintertext` macro with which the vertical spacing is tighter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*} & & \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}&=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}{s}}
                                {s^{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}{s}+{\omega}^{2}} & &\\
\shortintertext{On comparing}
 & & \omega=\sqrt{K_i} \quad \delta & =\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}} &&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{align*}
 \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}&=\frac{{\omega}^2+{2{\delta}}{\omega}{s}}
                                {s^{2}+2{\delta}{\omega}{s}+{\omega}^{2}} \\
\shortintertext{On comparing}
 \omega=\sqrt{K_i} \quad \delta & =\frac{K_p}{2\sqrt{K_{i}}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]